# substitude chracters after regexp sed/awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have got some problem with substituting characters between delimiters(axcluding them)
E.g.
file sample.txt

```
sample = 0;
        test "test0" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX010\
                      10101010101010101010101010101010101010";
         ...
        test "test11" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX01010101010101\
                      01010101010101010101010101010101010101"
         ...
 end;
 ...
 sample = 1001;
        test "test0" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX010\
                      10101010101010101010101010101010101010";
         ...
        test "test11" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX01010101010101\
                      01010101010101010101010101010101010101"
         ...
 end;

 sample = 1010;
        test "test0" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX010\
                      10101010101010101010101010101010101010";
         ...
        test "test11" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX01010101010101\
                      01010101010101010101010101010101010101"
         ...
 end;
 ...
```

and I want change all 1's to 0's in test11 in sample 1001. New text file should look like this:

```
sample = 0;
        test "test0" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX010\
                      10101010101010101010101010101010101010";
         ...
        test "test11" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX01010101010101\
                      01010101010101010101010101010101010101"
         ...
 end;
 ...
 sample = 1001;
        test "test0" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX010\
                      10101010101010101010101010101010101010";
         ...
        test "test11" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX00000000000000\
                      0000000000000000000000000000000000000"
         ...
 end;
 ...
 sample = 1010;
        test "test0" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX010\
                      10101010101010101010101010101010101010";
         ...
        test "test11" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX01010101010101\
                      01010101010101010101010101010101010101"
         ...
 end;
```

The problem is that when I use sed:

```
sed '/sample = 1001;/,/end;/ {/test11/,/;/ s/1/0/g} sample.txt'
```

it also changes number of test11 to test00

I tried also to change the name of test in the following way:

```
sed -i -e '/sample = 1001;/,/end;/ s/test11/tempname/' -e '/sample = 1001;/,/end;/ { /tempname/,/;/ s/1/0/g}' -e '/sample = 1001;/,/end;/ s/tempname/test11/'
```

but this is too slow (i need to change thousands of tests in thousands of samples)

Have You got any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the sample, then when that's found look for the test, isolate the tail section of the line you need to make changes in, then replace 1s with 0s within that section only, repeat until you find the next test or sample line:

```
$ cat tst.awk
inTest && (/test|sample/)    { inSample=inTest=0 }
/sample = 1001;/             { inSample = 1 }
inSample && /test "test11"/  { inTest = 1 }
inTest && match($0,/("[[:alnum:]\\]+|[[:digit:]]+");?$/) {
    head = substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
    tail = substr($0,RSTART)
    gsub(/1/,0,tail)
    $0 = head tail
}
{ print }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
sample = 0;
        test "test0" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX010\
                      10101010101010101010101010101010101010";
         ...
        test "test11" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX01010101010101\
                      01010101010101010101010101010101010101"
         ...
end;
...
sample = 1001;
        test "test0" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX010\
                      10101010101010101010101010101010101010";
         ...
        test "test11" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX00000000000000\
                      00000000000000000000000000000000000000"
         ...
end;

sample = 1010;
        test "test0" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX010\
                      10101010101010101010101010101010101010";
         ...
        test "test11" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX01010101010101\
                      01010101010101010101010101010101010101"
         ...
end;
...
```

Comment: but it also changes values in following samples
E.g.
sample = **1002**;
        test "test0" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX010\
                      10101010101010101010101010101010101010";
         ...
        test "test11" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX00000000000000\
                      00000000000000000000000000000000000000"
         ...
end;
end so on

Comment: No, it doesn't. It can't since it only sets the inSample flag when the line contains `sample = 1001` and it clears it whenever it hits an `end`. If you have some sample input that what I posted doesn't work for then update your question to show that input, the expected output and the actual output you're getting.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. I found the mistake but still it only changes values in the first line.

Comment: No, it doesn't. See the output I posted, I didn't make that up. Don't try to re-write the script by hand, just copy/paste it from this site into a file. The script is VERY simple, it just sets a flag and then does an operation when the flag is set. Again - If you have some sample input that what I posted doesn't work for then update your question to show that input, the expected output and the actual output you're getting

Comment: Hang on. I see now in your posted sample input that some of your second lines end in a semi-colon and others don't. My script assumes there's nothing after the terminating `"` because that's the way your sample input line that needed to be changed is posted. If that's wrong and there always IS or always ISN'T a terminating `;` or if that's optional - please update your question to clarify.

Comment: It sounds like your real input doesn't quite match the sample you posted so I updated my script to work whether or not there's a terminating `;` and whether or not there's an `end;` and whether or not `sample` is at the start of a line and if the number of digits after `sample` could be greater than 4. I also show it being ran against your updated sample input.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/sample = 1001/,/end/{/test "test11"/{N;:a;s/(= "[^"]*)1/\10/;ta}}' file
```

This narrows the search to `sample = 1001` and then again to `test11`. It then uses a loop to change any 1's to 0's following the `=` sign.

Comment: @esem what do you mean by "the first line"?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
sed '/sample = 1001;/,/end;/ {/test11/,/;/{s/1/0/g;s/test00/test11/}}' sample.txt
```

? ;-)

Comment: It'd fail if he had a "test12" entry after the "test11" entry in the same `sample` block, though, since it assumes a terminating semi-colon and there's isn't one at the end of the "test11" entry so the script would continue to make the substitutions through subsequent "test" blocks until it hit one that had a terminating semi-colon or the `end;` statement.

Comment: I am assuming from OP's snippet that perhaps except for the last entry, other entries are terminated by a `;`...

Answer (score 0):

Took some time to code this but it works.

```
#!/bin/bash

usage(){
    echo "Usage: $0 -sample x -test y"
    echo "Where x is the sample number y is the test number"
    exit 1
}

[ ! $# = 4 ] || [ ! $1 = "-sample" -a ! $3 = "-test" ] && usage

sample=$2
test=$4

sample_expanded=$(sed -e 's,sample = ,\
sample = ,g' < list.txt)
sample_preceding=$(head -n +$(($sample+1)) <<< "$sample_expanded")
sample_actual=$(tail -n +$(($sample+2)) <<< "$sample_expanded" |head -n 1)
sample_remaining=$(tail -n +$(($sample+3)) <<< "$sample_expanded" )

test_expanded=$(sed -e 's,test "test,\
test "test,g' <<< "$sample_actual" )
test_preceding=$(head -n +$(($test+1)) <<< "$test_expanded")
test_actual=$(tail -n +$(($test+2)) <<< "$test_expanded" |head -n 1)
test_remaining=$(tail -n +$(($test+3)) <<< "$test_expanded")

result_expanded=$(sed -e 's,=,=\
,g' <<< "$test_actual" )
result_name=$(head -n 1 <<< "$result_expanded")
result_value=$(tail -n 1 <<< "$result_expanded" |tr 1 0 ) # Change 1s to 0s

echo $sample_preceding $test_preceding $result_name $result_value $test_remaining $sample_remaining |
sed -e 's,sample = ,\
sample = ,g' \
-e's, test "test,\
    test "test,g' \
-e's,\\,\\\
                    ,g' \
-e's," end;," \
end;,g' > modified_list.txt
```

List.txt looks like this

```
sample = 0;
    test "test0" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX010\
                    10101010101010101010101010101010101010";
    test "test1" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX01010101010101\
                    01010101010101010101010101010101010101"
    test "test2" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX01010101010101\
                    01010101010101010101010101010101010101"
end;
sample = 1;
    test "test0" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX010\
                    10101010101010101010101010101010101010";
    test "test1" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX01010101010101\
                    01010101010101010101010101010101010101"
    test "test2" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX01010101010101\
                    01010101010101010101010101010101010101"
end;
sample = 2;
    test "test0" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX010\
                    10101010101010101010101010101010101010";
    test "test1" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX01010101010101\
                    01010101010101010101010101010101010101"
    test "test2" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX01010101010101\
                    01010101010101010101010101010101010101"
end;
sample = 3;
    test "test0" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX010\
                    10101010101010101010101010101010101010";
    test "test1" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX01010101010101\
                    01010101010101010101010101010101010101"
    test "test2" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX01010101010101\
                    01010101010101010101010101010101010101"
end;
```